# Rewire bathroom light / fan

Tags: wiring, exhaust-fan

We have a half bath that has a switch outside the door and another switch near the mirror/vanity inside.  The switch outside turns on a light at the ceiling and a (very loud) fan, and the switch inside turns on the lights above the mirror.

At a minimum, I want the inside switch to control the fan. Ideally, I want to exchange the wiring completely (outside switch controls vanity lights which are bright, inside switch controls ceiling light and fan).

Is this doable?  I'm very new to DIY, and have only recently purchased my first house. I can provide a picture if it helps.

Comment: Do you have access to an attic that will get you over the half bath?

Comment: Yes, can you provide photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: I don't have access to an attic that'll get me over the half bath. The half bath is on the first floor though, so maybe I can access it from 2nd fl. I'll provide pictures very soon.